# JQuery Accordion w/color changing headers?

Tags: jquery-ui, colors, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to make a JQuery accordion which will change it's style to .active{} when clicked, so the open accordion pane's header looks different from all the other panes of the accordion.  Here's what I have so far (it makes the accordion work, but the colors don't):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        nyah = $("#accordion").accordion({
            event: "mouseover",
            animate: "slow",
            active: 2,
        });

      $('#div0').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
            addMessage("change");      
            ui.oldHeader.removeclass('active');
            ui.newHeader.addclass('active');});

        nyah.accordion("activate", 1);
    });



    setTimeout(function () { nyah.accordion("activate", 0) }, 1000);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using jQueryui which already does this for you.  You can then just re-style the active item using CSS.  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Could you give me a example of restyling (or explain it more condescendingly)?  I'm not terribly experienced.